# How do I make a chatbox that reads a username from MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html, chat

Hey all, so I'm just trying to make a basic chatbox on my site that users will enter in a message and it will display in the box.

To get to the chatbox, users will already be logged into the site. So in the chatbox they wouldnt have to enter in their 'Name'. Just a message.

What would be the best way of doing this?

Comment: There's a whole lot of stuff you're leaving unanswered, for instance, your title question (read username from mysql) is entirely up to you.  What you need, though, are persistent connections. Basically, you have a JS loop which polls your server sequentially. Each poll takes at most 30 seconds, but you get a response if/when anything happens.

Comment: Could you please provide your table definition (just to start from something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't read the *username* from the database. If a user is already logged in, then you should have (or should use) a username in `$_SESSION["user"]` for example.

Your chatbox could use nothing more than a simple text `<input>` that you then receive server-side and store it into the database:

```
db("INSERT INTO chatbox (user, message, time) VALUES (?,?,?)")
-execute( array($_SESSION["user"], $_POST["input"], time()) );
```

Which then again is pretty easy to read out and display as a *chatbox*. (Maybe add a bit of AJAX polling once you have that working.)